# Работа с консолью

Tags: java, разработка-игр, консоль

В качестве изучения явы хочу сделать простенькую игру "собака @ гуляет по полю". Как обычно реализовывается работа с консолью в играх? Возможно ли как-то очищать экран при помощи класса console?

Answer (score 2):

Очистка консоли - `System.console().clear()`

*Также консоль можно сделать цветной, для чего можно воспользоваться предложенным [**здесь**](http://blogs.atlassian.com/devtools/2009/10/colour-your-console-ansicolor.html) методом.*

Comment: Спасибо большое. А не подскажите, как в консольных играх происходит отрисовка каждого кадра?

Comment: @n06rin Вообще говоря, консольные игры с перерисовкой всего фрейма - это изотерика. Но, если интересно, можете посмотреть [**здесь.**][1] [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/crazydev/130021/

Comment: А тогда каким образом организовать смену кадров?

Comment: @n06rin Ну, вызвать clear() и отрисовать заново.

Comment: Так ведь говоришь что изотерика. Просто может ты знал какой-либо другой способ.